# What causes your voice to crack?

Tags: voice, opera

I've heard many recording for Maria Callas and I noticed that her voice cracked many times.

One example is lucia mad scene studio recording 1953 when she sings "il dolce sono" between "il" and "dolce" you feel like her voice muted and repeated when she say "t'assedi".

So my question is what causes this?